# What could an indestructible person contribute to the world's technology?

Tags: technological-development, immortality

A doctor suddenly noticed that his patient seems to be indestructible, their injection doesn't penetrate through, until they even conducted basic experiments such as small knife cuts and other blunt damages.

Upon this discovery, the indestructible person was examined thoroughly, until he was really generalized as someone who is indestructible; a person like a very hard rock. His body could also never be affected by any chemical substance that harms him. Upon the series of test, he grew fond of science. In this story, the scientists can never(and would never) understand his body's data for they seem to be changing in a random pace.

Aside from his shield-like gift, he seems to be just a normal person, i.e; he cannot lift heavy objects but cannot be crush by them. Upon reaching his perfect age state, he stopped aging..  Years later when he started to wonder what could he contribute to science given that he is indestructible.

In what field of science does the indestructible yet average person contribute the best and in what way?

Note:

1. Let us not focus on the person himself, but to the what contribution he could give. Lets just describe him as indestructible. If this question is too broad, please specify in which detail it is lacking.
2. Even if he reproduce, his offspring will never get his ability so that the story will focus on the main character.

Comment: Seems to me that contributing to science is a function of the mind, not the body. I'd sooner ask this person to clean up stuff at Chernobyl [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster) and Fukushima  [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukushima_Daiichi_nuclear_disaster).

Comment: @Bookeater Good one. One of the things I'm thinking is that maybe he can be sent to the sun and harvest something in there. This act is part of my definition on contributing to science, not solely the intellectual research. The wittiest answer wins.

Comment: @swindles is he inert to all sorts of chemicals and radiation or just the ones  which cause harm to him?

Comment: @swindles so this is gonna be a race between the centre of the earth, Mars & Titan and the original proper housecleaning then.

Comment: @Abhishek I don't know how to put it in detail but _yes_ I want him to be inert but in such a way that I don't want his inertness to be put against him, i.e; "How can he survive if he is fully inert?" His data is unstable that he is inert enough to live and inert enough to be indestructible.

Comment: @Bookeater I think you can add that as an answer as long as you specify what he contributes and how he contributes. Maybe on the occasion,  it might be better for a trained astronaut to do the mars and titan mission than the indestructible guy(where he is better off on something else because he can explicitly clean the nuclear waste).

Comment: Hand him a few nukes, bolt him to the bottom of an [Orion style nuclear pulse rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_%28nuclear_propulsion%29) and send him to Mars/Europa/Titan to build a base. :D

Comment: does he shed skins?

Comment: @user6760 He cries, excretes, etc.. but on the moment they are no longer part of him, they lose their indestructibility.

Comment: @archmagus Haha. I wanted to upvote that but i don't have the ability yet. The thing is, a single average man would hardly produce the required time to create an interplanetary base. Maybe by the time he is halfway finishing it, our technology is already able to build one faster and cheaper. If you think this is not the case, provide your reply as an answer with an elaboration

Comment: @Swindles Being indestructable says nothing about how he would hold up from a large fall.  They say a helmet only helps somewhat in a collision because the brain, being loose in your skull, is slammed against the skull, and despite not takign external damage from a fall, that doesn't mean there wouldn't be internal damage.  A corollary to this:  can he hurt himself in any way?

Comment: @Neil He is indestructible physically both internally and externally. He cannot hurt himself.

Comment: So you have an indestructible man, and you're telling me that the indestructible man himself wouldn't be the most interesting contribution to science?  I think if there is anything he could contribute, it would be to be directly studied.  He seems to defy the laws of physics.

Comment: Does he need to eat or breath?

Comment: I imagine he could make some money letting people shoot him. It'd be a great way to blow off steam.

Comment: @DanSmolinske No, he can eat and breath but he doesn't require them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would fire him at absurd velocities into things. As he is the hardest substance known to man (or at least, available on Earth - Neutronium is unstable outside of a neutron start) this would allow for truly unique experiments. At impact energies which would pulverize, liquefy or vaporize projectiles made of any other material, he would remain solid. As he in unyielding this would create tremendous shockwaves and absurdly high compression, helping to replicate conditions usually found in stars and big bangs and such.
Who knows what advances in knowledge could be had from such experiments - they are beyond what is possible with any conventional material!

Comment: And then, inadvertantly, you discover his shield tolerance and you pulverize him.  "Man slaughtered in mad scientists' experiment!" will read the newspaper the next day.  Your reputation as a scientist is ruined.  You wish you had taken up programming instead.  What a sad day it is.

Comment: He'd certainly be a big hit!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a suicide mission? Can there be a mechanism for him to go back to our planet safely in-case this experiment yielded no valuable result? Although this one certainly sounds the greatest answer so far, I wouldn't want to risk the main asset

Comment: @swindles I would suggest doing the indestructible-man supercollisions experiments on Earth, perhaps using a light gas gun or a nuclear powered man launcher such as http://savvyparanoia.com/the-fastest-man-made-object-ever-a-nuclear-powered-manhole-cover-true/, once there is nothing useful to learn from 'safe' experiments, experiments with a high probability of losing the asset could be considered. For example he may or may not survive being fired into a Blackhole, but the scientists definitely won't get him back - so better leave 'Blackholeanaut' to last.

Answer (score 4):

Performing experiments in dangerous environments.

Currently we use non-tripulated vehicles in order to explore environments like the oceanic floor, the proximities of volcanos, other planets.

When a scientific imagines an experiment that might be interesting, he has to design:

- The actual experiment.
- The medition tools needed for the experiment, made of a material that can withstand the conditions.
- The vehicle that will perform the experiment, which must also be shielded from the environment.

Imagine that a scientist wants to find out how much time a steak must be put into hot lava to get cooked.

He has to put the test steak in a lava-resistant experiment, and then design a machine that lowers the recipient into the lava and retires it at a determined time. What is worse, if he wants to repeat the experiment with a new steak, he will have to retire the machine from the crater and "load" a new recipient with a new steak, and then position the machine at the crater again.

To make matters worse, if through all of this process (or, seeing the results), he wants to add a variation to the experiment, probably he will have to modify the machine's design.

A person would be way more flexible. You give him pack of steaks, a heat-resistant chronometer, and tell him to perform the test. No need to spend time designing a robot<sup>1</sup>, and if you want to change something in the experiment you just need to talk to that person.

A different issue would be if such a person would like having to endure such environments...

<sup>1</sup>: Or, if a robot is needed due to precision issues, it would be way simpler and serviced by such a man "in the spot".

Comment: I think this is an abstracted answer(which I think most people will think off). If you were to answer the question specifically, does this answer imply Volcanology for science research or would you shoot for archmagus ' Orion style nuclear pulse rocket?

Comment: I would vote against space exploration due to the possible psychic dangers of prolonged isolation (it would be nice to put a man on Mars in good health, but it will make you no good if he has become delusional). Also, space exploration involves long times of inactivity during travel (= unused advantage), and a single man on Mars cannot do very much (some experiments he has been given tools to perform, build a small building, but not a whole reasearch base).

Answer (score 3):

**Chemistry**

Such a person, with sufficient instructions should be able to experimentally determine practical applications of extremely unstable compounds like [FOOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioxygen_difluoride).
As a matter of fact there are a lot of such compounds about which scientists just speculate apparently due to their unstable and dangerous nature. Check out this [link](http://pipeline.corante.com/archives/2010/02/23/things_i_wont_work_with_dioxygen_difluoride.php) as well. Again this might not be the only case ,  a person who is indestructible can be employed to do any sort of dangerous experiments that a scientist can think of.